# How to resolve Stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, bluej

Im new to java and bluej. Now i tried to generate a new Book right after another Book is initialized:

```
 public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle)
    {
        author = bookAuthor;
        title = bookTitle;
        generatebook2();
    }
    public void generatebook2(){
        Book book2 = new Book("Jumbo","Fary");
    }
```

Somehow this wont work and i get a  error:

```
 Stackoverflow error: null
```

What did i wrong or how can i generate a new book onfly?

Comment: You are genererating a new book which is generating a new book which is generating a new book...... ect ect ect

Comment: Assuming this code ran to completion, how many books would you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have created is an infinite loop. In your `Book` constructor, you're creating a new `Book` object which calls that new object's constructor, which creates a new `Book` object...and so on and so on.

If you want to create another `Book` object immediately after the first, you'll need to call that from outside the object, from wherever you created the book in the first place.

Something like this:

```
Book book1 = new Book("John Smith", "Book1");
Book book2 = new Book("John Smith", "Book2");
```

And remove the `generateBook2` in the constructor.

Comment: Hey there downvoter, how about giving an explanation; what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the Book constructor recursively due to which you are getting the error.
May be you can write a new Constructor with different arguments and use it from the first constructor, assuming that you don't want to create two books from outside.

```
public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle)
{
    author = bookAuthor;
    title = bookTitle;
    generatebook2();
}
public Book(){
}


public void generatebook2(){
    Book book2 = new Book();
    book2.setAuthor("Jumbo");
    book2.setTitle("Fary");
}
```

Comment: in the method where you call the first book, create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be more obvious if we unroll the method generatebook 2

```
public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle)
    {
        author = bookAuthor;
        title = bookTitle;
        Book book2 = new Book("Jumbo","Fary"); //<-- unrolled generatebook2()
    }
```

Each book constructor, calls itself, with no end in sight. book2 never seems to do anything so the line effects nothing currently and could be removed

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Book' constructor, you are calling the method 'generatebook2()'.
The 'generatebook2()' method is calling the 'Book' constructor. Which then call the 'generatebook2()' method again and again.  Till you get a Stackoverflow exception (The stack is full from method calls).

Just remove the 'generatemethod2()' call from the constructor. Try this:

```
public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle)
{
    author = bookAuthor;
    title = bookTitle;
}

public Book generatebook2(){
    Book book2 = new Book("Jumbo","Fary");
    return book2;
}
```

If you want to create a new Book, then you can either call the constructor of 'Book' class, or call the method 'generatebook2()' from a book object.

Comment: @JohnSmith just remove the 'generatebook2()' call from the 'Book' constructor.

Comment: @JohnSmith Don't ask java to create an infinite number of books. Why is a new book created with the Book constructor anyway?

Comment: Is it possible that java generates a new book right after compiling?

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'after compiling' ? Your code will be executed only AFTER compiling.